# W3 CSS Validation Error / Font Face

Tags: w3c

this in my css file

error in https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'WYekan';
    src:url(fonts/WeWYekan.eot);
    src:url(fonts/WebYekan.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(fonts/WebYekan.woff) format("woff"),url(fonts/WebYekan.ttf) format("truetype"),url(fonts/WebYekan.svg#WebYekan) format("svg");
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    unicode-range:U+0600–06FF
}
```

Comment: @dmitreyg: Don’t you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Validation fails due to wrong dash character in the last line. The following text validates correctly: `unicode-range: U+0600-06FF;`